# Cant export data in MySqlbench

Tags: mysql, export, dump, workbench

When i go Server>Data export>select my db>Export Progress>Start Export I got this error: [mysqldump Version Mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNDA7.png)

I have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution, Open workbench, edit>preferences>administration> in Path to mysqldump Tool: i typed this: C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe and it worked fine.